# Insert multiple records in Sqlite using React Native

Tags: sqlite, react-native, expo

I try to insert multiple rows in React Native using SQLite.

this is the code:

```
rows = responseJson.rows;

     for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

        row=rows[i];
        query = `insert into ComuniUserAccountSync values (
            ${row.IDComuniUserAccountSync},
            ${row.IdAzienda},
            ${row.IdComune},
            ${row.IdUserAccount},
            '${row.DescrizioneComune}',
            '${row.DateLastUpdateMaster}'
        )`;


        db.transaction(
            tx => {
                tx.executeSql(query, [], (a,b) =>
                    console.log("!OK!!", JSON.stringify(b)), (a, b) =>
                        console.log("!ERROR!!", a, b)
                )

            }
       );

     }
```

but the result is that I insert only the last row, many times! This is the output with

```
db.transaction(
        tx => {
            tx.executeSql("select IDComuniUserAccountSync from ComuniUserAccountSync", [], (a,b) =>
            console.log("!OK!", JSON.stringify(b)), (a,b) =>
            console.log("!ERROR!!", JSON.stringify(b))
    );
        }
    );
```

!OK! {"rowsAffected":0,"rows":{"_array":[{"IDComuniUserAccountSync":72},{"IDComuniUserAccountSync":72},{"IDComuniUserAccountSync":72},{"IDComuniUserAccountSync":72},{"IDComuniUserAccountSync":72}, .......

ANY HELP??
Max

Comment: Did you try to use async/await inside your loop to make sure all your queries are executed, ??

Answer (score 0):

```
insertCategories(arrCateData){


  let keys = Object.keys(arrCateData[0])

  let arrValues = []

    var len = arrCateData.length;



    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      arrCateData[i].image = `"${arrCateData[i].image}"`;
      arrCateData[i].thumbnail = `"${arrCateData[i].thumbnail}"`;
      arrCateData[i].name = `"${arrCateData[i].name}"`;
      arrCateData[i].path = `"${arrCateData[i].path}"`;
      arrValues.push("(" + Object.values(arrCateData[i]) +")");
    }

    // console.log(arrValues)


  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.initDB().then((db) => {
      db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO category ("+ keys + ") VALUES " + String(arrValues)).then(([tx, results]) => {
          resolve(results);
        });
      }).then((result) => {
        this.closeDatabase(db);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });  

}
```

**this code may help you i just pass my array into function and it will insert data jusr change data according to ur requirement**

Comment: i have some issue with sqlite, i create the insert fetch delete functions and for some  reason it doesn't work for me. can you help me please ?